# get the effect of pressed button on enter key

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

have an input field and a fancy button. The button has a nice animation when clicked and add an entry to the list. I want to the button animation like it has just been pressed when I add the entry to the list via the enter key from the input field directly.

```
[a link](https://jsbin.com/buqarovuqo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)
```

Comment: Can't add the snippet!

Comment: Add a keylistener on your input field, listen for `enter` and then trigger `click()` for button i.e `document.getElementById('button').click()`

Comment: pls watch the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution: https://jsbin.com/jahaxodaja/1/edit?css,js,output

You can add a class name to your :active CSS rule and conditionally apply it to the button.

```
.button:active,
.button.active {
  ...
}
```

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {  
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
    button.classList.add('active');
    input();
    setTimeout(function() {
      button.classList.remove('active');
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: aaarrghhh, i was so close to the right solution :) thank you mate!

Comment: sure, can you be more specific about how the click and enter key press animations look different? do you mean the way # changes color?

Comment: I got it :) just add ".button.active:after" to the button. Is it possible to make the pressed animation a little bit slower? I mean when click on it physically via the mouse

Comment: nice. yep, you just have to change the delay values like so: -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; transition: all 0.3s linear; and setTimeout(function() { button.classList.remove('active'); }, 300);